# list group of logged in users

Tags: command-line, users, groups

I know I can see the list of logged in users, with the `who` command. 
But lets say, I want to see who in my group is logged on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usernames containing spaces are not allowed by default on Ubuntu, so this method should be robust:

```
who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | while read user; do for gid in $(id -G "$user"); do [ $gid -eq $(id -g) ] && printf '%s\n' "$user" && break; done; done | sort -u
```

- `who`: prints the list of currently logged in users;
- `cut -d ' ' -f 1`: prints the first space-separated field of each line;
- `while read user; do for gid in $(id -G "$user"); do [ $gid -eq $(id -g) ] && printf '%s\n' "$user" && break; done; done`: for each user, checks if one of the group ids of the current user is the same of the user running the command; if it is, prints the user;
- `sort -u`: sorts the users and removes potential duplicates.

```
% whoami
user
% who                     
foo      tty1         2016-01-27 16:49
user     tty2         2016-01-24 21:26 (:1)
user     pts/2        2016-01-27 16:33 (:1)
user     pts/4        2016-01-27 16:48 (:1)
% getent group user    
user:x:1000:
% who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | while read user; do for gid in $(id -G "$user"); do [ $gid -eq $(id -g) ] && printf '%s\n' "$user" && break; done; done | sort -u
user
% sudo usermod -aG user foo
% who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | while read user; do for gid in $(id -G "$user"); do [ $gid -eq $(id -g) ] && printf '%s\n' "$user" && break; done; done | sort -u
foo
user
```

Comment: what is foo btw?

Comment: @juggernaut1996 Just a user I use for testing stuff too dangerous to be tested on my main account.

Comment: good policy but i was expecting a more generic answer... i have seen this word appearing at many places ... does this have any special meaning in linux? at one place i read it is just a variable.. how correct am i?

Comment: @juggernaut1996 Indeed it does, but not only in Linux. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: I hadn't known about $id, that is really handy